# pdf of a mixed distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Consider the following steps to generate a value from a mixed distribution:

1. Generate $Z$ from $Bernoulli(0.5)$
2. If $Z=0$, draw $X$ from $Normal(0,1)$
3. If $Z=1$, draw $X$ from $Beta(1,3)$

I'm wondering what distribution will $X$ follow in this case. Will the pdf be $\frac{1}{2}f_1(x)+\frac{1}{2}f_2(x)$, where $f_1(x)$ is the pdf of $Normal(0,1)$ and $f_2(x)$ is the pdf of $Beta(1,3)$?

Comment: Yes, that would be the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

The density would look rather like the black curve below, being the average of the red and pink curves

[image]